# I'm confused with regards to how to model my class Enum which has two class Enum inside of it in a UML diagram

Tags: uml, staruml

How would I model my class diagraman where Inside said class I create two more classes? Here is my code in kotlin:

```
class Enum {

    enum class Electrodoméstico{
        Lavadora,
        Microondas,
        Refrigerador
    }
     enum class Colores{
        Blanco,
        Negro,
        Gris
    }
}
```

I also have to mention that my class `Enum` is in association with my super class `Electrodoméstico` where I implement my enum classes `Color` and `Electrodoméstico`.

Heres an image of my diagram.
[image: UML class diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UML 2.5 spec states this on p. 100:

> If a Classifier has ownedMembers that are Classifiers (including Behaviors – see 13.2), a conforming tool may provide the option to show the owned Classifiers, and relationships between them, diagrammatically nested within a separate compartment of the owning Classifier’s rectangle. Unless otherwise specified, the name of such a compartment shall be derived from the corresponding metamodel property, pluralized if that property has multiplicity greater than 1. So, for example, a compartment showing the contents of the property nestedClassifier for a Class (see 11.4.2) shall be called “nested classifiers;” a compartment showing the contents of the property ownedBehavior for a BehavioredClassifier shall be called “owned behaviors.”

I'm using EA for modeling which allows to enlarge the class frame to fit the nested enums inside. However, it does not allow to create a named compartment. But honestly the rendering will be obvious for any reader also without the label.

You could as well just abstract the whole thing. There is probably no force to have the enums encapsulated. So you could well model it as you did with associations. Your code would then just be some implementation variant.

Comment: Out of curiosity: would you then show color and tipo as parts in the classifier compartment or would you keep them in the property compartment?

Comment: @Christophe Well, just where is free space. Probably I would show them without any other compartments (in EA). That will leave just the class frame and no special compartment. Simple but understandable.

Comment: But most likely I would model the enums not as encapsulated and use a dependency. But that really depends on the context.